# sympy pretty printing causes console to freeze

Tags: sympy, pretty-print

I had a fresh install of `miniconda, sympy, spyder, qtconsole, matplotlib`, and tried out `sympy` under `spyder`. However, the output of anything from the console freezes the kernel, making the session irresponsive:
[image: screenshot]

Notice the red square at the upper right corner, indicating evaluating never stops. If I turn off pretty_print, the output can appear:
[image: screenshot 2]

I have latex installed and work fine. I tried playing with `init_printing` but nothing works unless I turn off `pretty_print`. I do need the output to be readable. I uninstalled and reinstalled but no luck. How do I fix the output problem for `pretty_print`? The system is windows 10, and everything is default latest version as of 7/10/2021.

Comment: This sounds like a bug so best to open a GitHub issue with either Spyder or SymPy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and I got around it by explicitly calling init_printing(use_latex='mathjax'). As the doc below indicates, by default use_latex=None and sympy should be able to find a latex rendering option automatically, but it seems to fail to do so and somehow gets stuck.

```
use_latex : string, boolean, or None, default=None
        If True, use default LaTeX rendering in GUI interfaces (png and
        mathjax);
        if False, do not use LaTeX rendering;
        if None, make a guess based on the environment;
        if 'png', enable latex rendering with an external latex compiler,
        falling back to matplotlib if external compilation fails;
        if 'matplotlib', enable LaTeX rendering with matplotlib;
        if 'mathjax', enable LaTeX text generation, for example MathJax
        rendering in IPython notebook or text rendering in LaTeX documents;
        if 'svg', enable LaTeX rendering with an external latex compiler,
        no fallback
```